# How to make either of the fields mandatory in XML schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xsd

I have a requirement like either `ParcelNumber` or co-ordinates like `CoordinateX` or `CoordinateY` mandatory and these two contains different hierarchy in XML . So if the input xml contains parcel number it should return success or if it contains both co-ordinates, then it should return success.I created following schema ,and it will return success if i send only parcel number, but if i send Co-ordinates it will fail ,it is asking to send parcel number which is wrong.How to achieve it.In Nutshell i have following question

```
1>If i send both coordinates  and no parcel number it should return success
2>IF i send x coordinate then it should fail and ask to send Y co ordinate
```

Following is what i have done so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="NOCPlantMapRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Applicationtype" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="RelatedNOCRefNumber" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="WorkLocation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="LocationType"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="LocationType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="ParcelNumber" type="ParcelNumberType" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="WorkArea" type="WorkAreaType" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="Roads" type="RoadListType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="RoadListType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="WorkLocationRoad" type="WorkLocationRoadType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="WorkLocationRoadType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="RoadName" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CommunitiesListType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="WorkLocationRoad" type="WorkLocationRoadType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ParcelNumberType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="WorkAreaType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="WorkArea" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Coordinates" minOccurs="1" type="CoordinatesType"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Communities" type="CommunitiesListType" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CoordinatesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" type="WorkLocationCoordinateType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="WorkLocationCoordinateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CoordinateX" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="CoordinateY" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**EDIT**
Any idea of how to use `choice` properly here

Comment: If this question is about XML Schema, tag the question with XSD. Otherwise, people interested in XSD will not find it. Next, if you have a question about XML Schema, please always post sample XML documents that go with it. Ideally, one XML document that should be valid against this schema and another that should be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:-

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ParcelNumber" />
    <xs:element name="CoOrdinates" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="CoOrdinates" />
    <xs:element name="ParcelNumber" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

Comment: @avinashHow should i fit this in to my xsd ,since the hierarchy is different which is like WorkLocationCoordinateType->CoordinatesType->WorkAreaType->WorkLocationRoadType

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <xsd:complexType name="WorkLocationCoordinateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CoordinateX" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="CoordinateY" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
​
```

Comment: still even after filling Co-ordinates it is showing Parcel number need to sent

Comment: Then add minOccurs="0" to Parcel Number.

Comment: if i do like that above problem will be solved ,but if i didnot put anything like parcelnumber and coordinates null, it still shows null, how to fix it

Comment: i mean if both parcel number and cooordinates are null then it is showing success which should not happen.Either of them should present